# How to include a space in str_detect for regex pattern

Tags: r

I am working with a data set of text and I am trying to use `str_extract()` to detect a list of side effects from my data set text. It works well as long as the side effect is one word (i.e. 'headache') but if it is multiple words it is not detected by `str_extract()` (i.e. "flu like"). I will include my code below:

```
symptoms <- c( "sore", "headache", "flu like", "no side effects")

symptoms <- as.data.frame(symptoms)

symptomsRegex <- stringr::str_c(symptoms$symptoms, collapse = "|")
```

And an example data set:

```
df <- c("I have no side effects", "My arm is sore", "I have a headache", "I had flu like symptoms")

df <- as.data.frame(df)

df %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, df) %>% # from library(tidytext)
  mutate(sideEffect = str_extract(word, symptomsRegex)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(sideEffect))
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The problem is you are tokenizing by word, and then searching for multiple words (ngrams) within a list of words. You can do either as proposed in the answers, or tokenize by bigrams, trigrams, etc and search those clusters of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(sideEffects = str_extract(df, symptomsRegex))
```

**Output**

```
                       df     sideEffects
1  I have no side effects no side effects
2          My arm is sore            sore
3       I have a headache        headache
4 I had flu like symptoms        flu like
```